# ASP.NET Core 6 : AddAccessTokenManagement with Redis cache

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project which creates several `HttpClient`s to access several external resources using the approach illustrated [here](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/worker.html).

I'm using the `AddAccessTokenManagement` and `AddClientAccessTokenHandler` extension methods from `IdentityModel.AspNetCore` on application start-up, as illustrated in the linked article. I would like to use Redis Cache to store the tokens instead of the in-memory cache, because the destination environment for the solution contains several app services behind a load balancer, each of which has 10+ instances (I want to avoid each of these maintaining their own memory cache).

Is it possible to use a different cache (e.g. Redis) while using this approach?

Start-up:

```
foreach (var tokenEndpointConfiguration in tokenEndpointConfigurations)
{
    services.AddAccessTokenManagement(options =>
    {
        options.Client.Clients.Add(tokenEndpointConfiguration.Name, new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest()
        {
            Address = tokenEndpointConfiguration.TokenUrl,
            ClientId = tokenEndpointConfiguration.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = tokenEndpointConfiguration.ClientSecret
        });
    });

    services.AddHttpClient(tokenEndpointConfiguration.Name, c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri(new tokenEndpointConfiguration.BaseUrl);
    })
    .AddClientAccessTokenHandler(tokenClientName: tokenEndpointConfiguration.Name);
}

services.AddSingleton<HttpClientSelectorService>();
```

`HttpClientSelectorService`:

```
private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
private readonly ILogger<HttpClientSelectorService> _logger;

public HttpClientSelectorService(ILogger<HttpClientSelectorService> logger, List<HttpClientConfig> tokenEndpointConfigs, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    _tokenEndpointConfigs = tokenEndpointConfigs;
    _logger = logger;
    _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
}

public virtual HttpClient GetHttpClientByResource(string resourceUrl, Guid correlationId)
{
    var tokenEndpointConfig = GetTokenEndpointConfigByResource(resourceUrl, correlationId);
    return _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(tokenEndpointConfig.Name);
}
```

Comment: Did you find anything on this?

Comment: As far as I can see, it's not possible. The alternative is to use custom handlers for authentication, but it makes things considerably more complicated. The IdentityModel documentation states that you can override the caching mechanism, but it's not clear how to do that.

Comment: After some digging, I found that IdentityModel.AspnetCore has been replaced by Duende.AccessTokenManagement (https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Duende.AccessTokenManagement/wiki/Customizing-Client-Credentials-Token-Management) and this apparently supports different caches. I'll try this and I'll update this question if I manage to make it work.

Comment: It is possible actually. You just need to provide an implementation of the IDistributedCache. There is a community extension for postgres and an official for Redis (and NCache or MSSQL and some others). The default implementation uses an in memory cache for the jwt.